# How can I get all Video IDs form a YouTube Channel by using YouTube API?

Tags: php, youtube

Is there any way to get all the video ids from a youtube channel?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, FransAlkemade! Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but we won't be able to provide generic answer. Please see “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API v2 was depreciated last year. Spend some time looking into v3,...it's quite a bit different in that you'll need to make a series of calls to get the same thing you were getting in v2 and none of your old code will work, but has better control in other ways,...it's just awful chatty is all.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take an example [channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/MichaelJackson/videos) and its example [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfrV_6yWbEg).

Now we have to get the `channel_id` from the `video_id` from its `URL` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfrV_6yWbEgwe which is `PfrV_6yWbEgwe`

For getting the `channel_id` using the `video_id`, you can use the  [videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint of the YouTube Data API - [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22PfrV_6yWbEg%22%5D%7D).

Result:

```html
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "qh1OskO-aIVgApaf_ko2NP56aTw",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "eIO610C5Nr92qVJbX_pQYb9kc0Y",
      "id": "PfrV_6yWbEg",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-10-28T22:48:23Z",
        "channelId": "UCulYu1HEIa7f70L2lYZWHOw",
        "title": "Michael Jackson - Who Is It (Official Video)",
        "description": "“Who Is It” by Michael Jackson\nListen to Michael Jackson: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/_listenYD\n\nMichael Jackson’s “Who Is It” short film, directed by David Fincher, spins a dark, expressionistic tale of heartbreak over a lover’s infidelity that complements this worldwide Top 10 hit song.\n\nFollow Michael Jackson:\nFacebook: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followFI\nTwitter: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followTI\nInstagram: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followII\nWebsite: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followWI\nSpotify: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followSI\nYouTube: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/subscribeYD\n\nChorus:\nIs it a friend of mine\n(Who is it?)\nIs it my brother?\n(Who is it?)\nSomebody hurt my soul\n(Who is it?)\nI can't take this stuff no more\n\n#MichaelJackson #Dangerous #WhoIsIt",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PfrV_6yWbEg/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PfrV_6yWbEg/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PfrV_6yWbEg/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "michaeljacksonVEVO",
        "tags": [
          "1991",
          "new jack swing",
          "Dangerous",
          "Teddy Riley",
          "fourth album",
          "ocean way studios",
          "record one studios",
          "michael jackson",
          "michael jackson Who Is It",
          "michael jackson dangerous live",
          "michael jackson dangerous album",
          "michael jackson dangerous tour",
          "michael jackson dangerous lyrics",
          "michael jackson songs",
          "beat it",
          "billie jean",
          "michael jackson pyt",
          "michael jackson thriller",
          "michael jackson black or white",
          "smooth criminal",
          "man in the mirror",
          "why",
          "you"
        ],
        "categoryId": "10",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Michael Jackson - Who Is It (Official Video)",
          "description": "“Who Is It” by Michael Jackson\nListen to Michael Jackson: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/_listenYD\n\nMichael Jackson’s “Who Is It” short film, directed by David Fincher, spins a dark, expressionistic tale of heartbreak over a lover’s infidelity that complements this worldwide Top 10 hit song.\n\nFollow Michael Jackson:\nFacebook: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followFI\nTwitter: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followTI\nInstagram: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followII\nWebsite: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followWI\nSpotify: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/followSI\nYouTube: https://MichaelJackson.lnk.to/subscribeYD\n\nChorus:\nIs it a friend of mine\n(Who is it?)\nIs it my brother?\n(Who is it?)\nSomebody hurt my soul\n(Who is it?)\nI can't take this stuff no more\n\n#MichaelJackson #Dangerous #WhoIsIt"
        },
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en-US"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

In this case, the `channel_id` of the example video `PfrV_6yWbEg` is: `UCulYu1HEIa7f70L2lYZWHOw`.

Then, with this `channel_id`, change the second character to `U` as follows:

- Unmodified: UCulYu1HEIa7f70L2lYZWHOw
- Modified: U**U**ulYu1HEIa7f70L2lYZWHOw

This modified id is the **Uploads** playlist of that said YouTube channel.

With this Uploads playlist_id, you can use the [Playlistitem:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint of the YouTube Data API to retrieve all the uploaded videos from the autogenerated channel.

This is [the example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUulYu1HEIa7f70L2lYZWHOw%22%7D) with the uploads `playlist_id` described in this answer.